# Pandas: Groupby and sum customer profit, for every 6 months, starting from users first transaction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset like this:

| Customer ID | Date | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4/13/2018 | 10.00 |
| 1 | 4/26/2018 | 13.27 |
| 1 | 10/23/2018 | 15.00 |
| 2 | 1/1/2017 | 7.39 |
| 2 | 7/5/2017 | 9.99 |
| 2 | 7/7/2017 | 10.01 |
| 3 | 5/4/2019 | 30.30 |

I'd like to groupby and sum profit, for every 6 months, starting at each users first transaction.

The output ideally should look like this:

| Customer ID | Date | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4/13/2018 | 23.27 |
| 1 | 10/13/2018 | 15.00 |
| 2 | 1/1/2017 | 7.39 |
| 2 | 7/1/2017 | 20.00 |
| 3 | 5/4/2019 | 30.30 |

The closest I've seem to get on this problem is by using:

```
df.groupby(['Customer ID',pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='6M', closed='left')])['Profit'].sum().reset_index()
```

But, that doesn't seem to sum starting on a users first transaction day.

If the changing of dates is not possible (ex. customer 2 date is 7/1/2017 and not 7/5/2017), then at least summing the profit so that its based on each users own 6 month purchase journey would be extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I can get you the first of the month until you find a more perfect solution.

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y")
df = (
    df
    .set_index("Date")
    .groupby(["Customer ID"])
    .Profit
    .resample("6MS")
    .sum()
    .reset_index(name="Profit")
)
print(df)

   Customer ID       Date  Profit
0            1 2018-04-01   23.27
1            1 2018-10-01   15.00
2            2 2017-01-01    7.39
3            2 2017-07-01   20.00
4            3 2019-05-01   30.30
```